# NSInternalInconsistencyException in iOS 7.1, But works in 8.1?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have a tableviewcontroller, and it's working in ios 8.1 but not working on ios 7.1. I have this exception

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: table view row height must
>   not be negative - provided height for index path ( 2 indexes [0, 0]) is nan

I think that it is about unified api. I tried many simulator which is 7.1, not working but if i try a simulator which is 8.1, it works. What should I do?

**Edit**: I overried GetHeightForRow method but its the same..

I am using Xamarin.ios with C#.

Comment: Can you add the code that's relevant for this problem? Maybe then it becomes more clear.

Comment: What happens if you avoid overriding `GetHeightForRow`?